# Restrict cookies in WebView to first party cookies

Tags: android, cookies, webview

I'm developing an app which uses a `WebView` as a tiny in-app-browser. I like to restrict the cookies that are set for the app via this `WebView` to first party ones.

E.g. if the in-app-browser visits **http://goodhost.com** which loads a script or something from **http://badhost.com**, then the in-app-browser should only allow cookie setting for cookies from **http://goodhost.com**

Is this Possible? Any workarounds if not?